# Is there a way to get a list of playlists containing a particular song in Spotipy (Spotify Python Api)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I want to create a recommendation system of sorts, and I'm trying to find playlists with a given song in them to see what other songs people listen alongside that. Is there a way to do that using the Spotify API in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. You could however use the endpoint `https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations`to get related songs to a song. You give a song, artist and genre to Spotify and they give a playlist with similar songs back to you. That could allow you to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an example of a similar system in action

[Playlist Miner](https://playlistminer.playlistmachinery.com)